# Exporting a rig to unreal, one of the bones is excluded or not there? it is greyed out when I open it in Unreal

Tags: animation, rigging, export, bones, unreal-engine

Exporting a rig to unreal, one of the bones is excluded or not there? it is greyed out when I open it in Unreal

I'm not sure what exactly is happening when it gets to Unreal, any advice or solutions would be great

[image: Mag bone is Greyed out]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think we'll need to see your Blend file to work out what's going on. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link to it, then edit your question and paste the link into it. Just the armature should be sufficient if the file is very large.

Comment: thanks for responding, I attached the blend file

Comment: That Blend file is producing several errors when you try to load it, specifically: "Info: Cannot find lib 'D:\Downloads\ins2 rig.blend'" which leads to other 'missing' errors and means that nothing is visible in the 3D view, File > External Data > Report Missing Files  also reports that 'ins2 rig.blend' is missing.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was working off a linked file to export separately both arms and weapon animations. I put in a new link to a new blender file with the model and rig, hopefully this works. But I also found another problem I think? in the new blender file, the mag bone isn't parented to the mesh, and parenting it again resets the meshs transform scale.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you intended to do it but you appear to have keyframed the Scale of your armature. The scale of the gun itself is currently set to 0.090 too. I've no idea whether this will cause problems exporting though, not having any experience of exporting animation.  Perhaps someone else here could comment?